# Problem to create a slideshow of images from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, image, slideshow, jlabel

I am a beginner in Java and I am doing a small project which consists of displaying plant images with JComBox from MySQL database and a JLabel to display an image "showview" or "slideshow" (I don't know the expression very well in English) .

For the images, I have to import them in a local src/... folder and for that I use a byteArrayOutputStream method which works well.

When I select an item in the list for the first time, the images are well displayed in the JLabel and the showview works well with the buttons.

On the other hand when I change selection in my list, my information is well changed in the different JTextField but it is always the same images of the first selection that are displayed in my slideshow and yet they are well changed in the source file.

Here is my code with constructor class:

\\

```
     package com.dug.plantId;

/*** Constructor images DB ***/ 

public class Plant {

    String id;
    byte[] image1, image2, image3, image4, image5;

    public Plant(
        byte[] image1, byte[] image2, byte[] image3, byte[] image4, byte[] image5, String id) {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public byte[] getImage1() {
        return image1;
    }

    public void setImage1(byte[] image1) {
        this.image1 = image1;
    }

    public byte[] getImage2() {
        return image2;
    }

    public void setImage2(byte[] image2) {
        this.image2 = image2;
    }

    public byte[] getImage3() {
        return image3;
    }

    public void setImage3(byte[] image3) {
        this.image3 = image3;
    }

    public byte[] getImage4() {
        return image4;
    }

    public void setImage4(byte[] image4) {
        this.image4 = image4;
    }

    public byte[] getImage5() {
        return image5;
    }

    public void setImage5(byte[] image5) {
        this.image5 = image5;
    }
}
```

\\

Class with code for the DB connection and factoring images to a folder (src)

\\

```
      package com.dug.plantId;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBConnection {

        private Connection connetion = null;
    private Statement stmt = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;

    private MyPanels DBConnection;

    /*** Connection to MySQL ***/

    public DBConnection() {
        try {
            this.connetion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbarbres?" +
                "user=Dug&password=Java427");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    /***  Method to create a list imported from the DB ***/

    public List<Plant> searchPlant(String nom) {
        List<Plant> listPlants = new ArrayList<Plant> ();
        try {
            stmt = connetion.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dbarbres.tblarbre where nomLatin like '%" + nom + "%' or nomCommun like '%" + nom + "%'");
            byte[] image = null;

            while (rs.next()) {
                listPlants.add(new Plant(rs.getBytes("image1"), rs.getBytes("image2"),
                    rs.getBytes("image3"), rs.getBytes("image4"), rs.getBytes("image5"), rs.getInt("id") + ""));

                /***  Calling the methods of FileOutputStream to display the images of the DB. ***/

                image1Generate();
                image2Generate();
                image3Generate();
                image4Generate();
                image5Generate();
                MyPanels.imagesImportToList();

                /***  Call a static method to display the first image ***/

                MyPanels.displayImage1();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // handle any errors
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return listPlants;
    }

    /***  Methods for generating MySQL DB images to a local folder (src) ***/

    public void image1Generate() throws SQLException, IOException {

        int i = rs.getInt("id");
        Blob ph = rs.getBlob("image1");
        if (ph == null) {
            return;
        }
        int length = (int) ph.length();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        InputStream in = ph.getBinaryStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/photos/photo1.jpg");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        while ((length = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("writing " + length + " bytes");
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.writeTo(outputStream); in .close();
    }

    public void image2Generate() throws SQLException, IOException {

        int i = rs.getInt("id");
        Blob ph = rs.getBlob("image2");
        if (ph == null) {
            return;
        }
        int length = (int) ph.length();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        InputStream in = ph.getBinaryStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/photos/photo2.jpg");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((length = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("writing " + length + " bytes");
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.writeTo(outputStream); in .close();
    }

    public void WindowsMainPanelsAffichage() {
        DBConnection affichageImage = new DBConnection();
        affichageImage.DBConnection = new MyPanels();
    }

    public void image3Generate() throws SQLException, IOException {

        int i = rs.getInt("id");
        Blob ph = rs.getBlob("image3");
        if (ph == null) {
            return;
        }
        int length = (int) ph.length();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        InputStream in = ph.getBinaryStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/photos/photo3.jpg");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((length = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("writing " + length + " bytes");
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.writeTo(outputStream); in .close();
    }

    public void image4Generate() throws SQLException, IOException {

        int i = rs.getInt("id");
        Blob ph = rs.getBlob("image4");
        if (ph == null) {
            return;
        }
        int length = (int) ph.length();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        InputStream in = ph.getBinaryStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/photos/photo4.jpg");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((length = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("writing " + length + " bytes");
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.writeTo(outputStream); in .close();
    }

    public void image5Generate() throws SQLException, IOException {

        int i = rs.getInt("id");
        Blob ph = rs.getBlob("image5");
        if (ph == null) {
            return;
        }
        int length = (int) ph.length();
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        InputStream in = ph.getBinaryStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("src/photos/photo5.jpg");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((length = in .read(buffer)) != -1) {
            System.out.println("writing " + length + " bytes");
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        out.writeTo(outputStream); in .close();
    }
}
```

\\

Class with code for generate frame, panels, jlabel for images and buttons sliders.

\\

```
package com.dug.plantId;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

public class MyPanels extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JComboBox jComboBoxNomCommun;
    private JComboBox jComboBoxNomLatin;

    static ImageIcon[] s;
    static JLabel jLabelImages;
    private static JButton b1;
    private static JButton b2;
    int i, l1;

    public MyPanels() {
        super();
        initComposantsPanel1();
    }

    /****  main ****/

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MyPanels launchWindowsProg = new MyPanels();
        launchWindowsProg.generatePanels();
        launchWindowsProg.buttonsSlideShow();
    }

    /***  Initialize components of panel1. ***/

    private void initComposantsPanel1() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


        JLabel listeAlphabetiqueNomLatin = panel1LabelCell(GridBagConstraints.WEST, 2, 1, "Liste alphabétique nom latin: ");
        jComboBoxNomLatin = panel1ComboBoxNomLatin(GridBagConstraints.WEST, 3, 1, "");

        
        JLabel listeAlphabetiqueNomCommunTextField = panel1LabelCell(GridBagConstraints.WEST, 2, 2, "Liste alphabétique nom commun: ");
        jComboBoxNomCommun = panel1ComboBoxNomCommun(GridBagConstraints.WEST, 3, 2, "");
    }

    /*** Manufacturers for the different components ***/

    public JLabel panel1LabelCell(int GridBagConstraints, int positionGridx, int positionGridy, String labelLigne) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 300, 3, 20);
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints;
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = positionGridx;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = positionGridy;
        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(labelLigne);
        this.add(jLabel, gridBagConstraints);
        return jLabel;
    }

    /*** Constructor  panel1 (JComboBox) ***/

    public JComboBox panel1ComboBoxNomCommun(int GridBagConstraints, int positionGridx, int positionGridy, String text) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 10;
        JComboBox jComboBoxNomCommun = new JComboBox();
        jComboBoxNomCommun.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(225, 23));
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = positionGridx;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = positionGridy;

        /*** DB connection ***/

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        /*** Import list DB to jComboBoxNomCommun ***/

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbarbres?" +
                "user=Dug&password=Java427");
            st = con.createStatement();
            String s = "select * from tblarbre";
            rs = st.executeQuery(s);
            while (rs.next()) {
                jComboBoxNomCommun.addItem(rs.getString(
                    "nomCommun"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
        } finally {
            try {
                st.close();
                rs.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR CLOSE");
            }
        }
        
        jComboBoxNomCommun.addActionListener(e -> {

            String typedText = ((JTextField) jComboBoxNomCommun.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();

            DBConnection dBConnection = new DBConnection();
            List<Plant> findedPlant = dBConnection.searchPlant(typedText);

            for (Plant plant: findedPlant) {

            }
        });
        this.add(jComboBoxNomCommun, gridBagConstraints);
        return jComboBoxNomCommun;
    }
    private JComboBox panel1ComboBoxNomLatin(int GridBagConstraints, int positionGridx, int positionGridy, String text) {
        GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 10;
        JComboBox jComboBoxNomLatin = new JComboBox();
        jComboBoxNomLatin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(225, 23));
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = positionGridx;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = positionGridy;
        this.add(jComboBoxNomLatin, gridBagConstraints);

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        /***  Import liste DB to jComboBoxNomLatin ***/

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbarbres?" +
                "user=Dug&password=Java427");
            st = con.createStatement();
            String s = "select * from tblarbre";
            rs = st.executeQuery(s);
            while (rs.next()) {
                jComboBoxNomLatin.addItem(rs.getString(
                    "nomLatin"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR");
        } finally {
            try {
                st.close();
                rs.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR CLOSE");
            }
        }
        jComboBoxNomLatin.addActionListener(e -> {

            String typedText = ((JTextField) jComboBoxNomLatin.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).getText();

            DBConnection dBConnection = new DBConnection();
            List<Plant> findedPlant = dBConnection.searchPlant(typedText);

            for (Plant plant: findedPlant) {
            }
        });
        return jComboBoxNomLatin;
    }

    /*** Generate panels ***/

    void generatePanels() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1);
            panel1.setBounds(10, 10, 1400, 200);
            panel2.setBounds(720, 250, 700, 530);
            panel2.setBorder(border);
            MyPanels myPanels = new MyPanels();
            panel1.add(myPanels);
            frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setSize(1450, 900);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            /*** Add buttons for showview images***/

            panel2.add(b1);
            panel2.add(b2);
            jLabelImages = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
            panel2.add(jLabelImages, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        });
    }

    /*** Import images to a list***/

    public static void imagesImportToList() {
        s = new ImageIcon[5];
        s[0] = new ImageIcon("src/photos/photo1.jpg");
        s[1] = new ImageIcon("src/photos/photo2.jpg");
        s[2] = new ImageIcon("src/photos/photo3.jpg");
        s[3] = new ImageIcon("src/photos/photo4.jpg");
        s[4] = new ImageIcon("src/photos/photo5.jpg");
    }
    /***  Method of displaying the slideshow images ***/

    public void buttonsSlideShow() {

        b1 = new JButton("<<");
        b2 = new JButton(">>");

        b1.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " First image");
                } else {
                    i = i - 1;
                    jLabelImages.setIcon(s[i]);
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b2) {
                if (i == s.length - 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Last Image");
                } else {
                    i = i + 1;
                    jLabelImages.setIcon(s[i]);
                }
            }
        });
        b2.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "First image");
                } else {
                    i = i - 1;
                    jLabelImages.setIcon(s[i]);
                }
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b2) {
                if (i == s.length - 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Last Image");
                } else {
                    i = i + 1;
                    jLabelImages.setIcon(s[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}

    /*** Show image1 after selection in the JCombobox list  ***/

    static void displayImage1() {
        String displayImage1 = "src/photos/photo1.jpg";
        ImageIcon image1 = new ImageIcon(displayImage1);
        jLabelImages.setIcon(image1);
    }
}
```

\\

I tried everything but I can't get it, maybe there is a solution with embedded resource via a URL. A URL that can be obtained using Class.getResource() but I don't have enough knowledge.

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found the solution, I created an ImageIcon object for each generated image in the src folder, so I added this line in each imageGenerate method:

image1 = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/photos/photo1.jpg")));

and previously added in variable declaration:

```
static ImageIcon image1;
static ImageIcon image2;
static ImageIcon image3;
static ImageIcon image4;
static ImageIcon image5;
```

It is not necessary to create the image in a folder.
Here is the code for the image1Generate method:

```
public void image1Generate() throws SQLException, IOException {

    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("image1");

    int blobLength = (int) blob.length();

    byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
    final BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(blobAsBytes));

    image1 = (new ImageIcon(bufferedImage));
    }
```

Then I modified the imagesImportToList method accordingly:

```
    public static void imagesImportToList() {
 
    s[0] = image1;
    s[1] = image2;
    s[2] = image3;
    s[3] = image4;
    s[4] = image5;
}
```

and finally, so that my slideshow doesn't get tangled up and return to image1 at each change, I added where necessary: i = 0;